# How to get Next Month in Mon yyyy Format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have one table that get dates as `SaleDate` formatted like this

```
##SaleDate##
_________
Oct 13  
--------
Nov 13  
--------  
Dec 13  
-------- 
Jan 14  
--------
```

How can I get the next month from previous date formats?

Comment: Have you tried DateAdd? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Have you thought of redesigning the table so that it contains a date instead of a string?

Comment: How could i do this using only DATEADD()

Answer (score 0):

By setting min and max date you can get the list of date like below

```
       DECLARE @OldestDate DATE
    DECLARE @maxDate DATE 
    SET @OldestDate = '09/29/2013' -- (SELECT MIN(SALEDATE) FROM YOURTABLE)
    SET @maxDate = '12/19/2014' -- (SELECT MAX(SALEDATE) FROM YOURTABLE)

 ; WITH dates([DateCounter]) AS 
  (
    SELECT @OldestDate AS [DateCounter] 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(month,+1,[DateCounter])
    FROM DATES 
    WHERE [DateCounter] < CAST(@maxDate AS DATE)
  )

    SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[DateCounter]),3) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,[DateCounter])
    FROM dates
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Here is the working example on [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64221/1)

Answer (score 0):

With some long convoluted inline functions:

```
DECLARE @V VARCHAR(6)
SET @V = 'Jan 14'

SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),DATEADD(m,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01 ' + @V,106)),6),6)


SELECT RIGHT(
    CONVERT(
        VARCHAR(9),
            DATEADD(m,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01 ' + SaleDate,106))
        ,6)
 ,6)
FROM YourTable
```